# How to set mikrobus gpio pin in PIC16F1526 to connect PCA9685 via I2C in mikroC Pro for pic compiler

Tags: firmware

I want to control servo motor using microcontrollar(PIC16F1526). The microcontrollar is connected to PCA9685 module via I2C. I have used servo library in mikroC pro for PIC compiler but is not working to control the servo motor.

Thank you

```
void applicationTask()
{
     servo_setPosition(_SERVO_MOTOR_1, 0);
     Delay_ms( 2000 );
     servo_setPosition(_SERVO_MOTOR_1, 90);
     Delay_ms( 1000 );
     servo_setPosition(_SERVO_MOTOR_1, 180);
     Delay_ms( 2000 );
     servo_setPosition(_SERVO_MOTOR_1, 90);
     
     Delay_ms( 1000 );
}
void applicationInit()
{
    servo_i2cDriverInit( 1, 2, 0x40, 0x14 );
    servo_init( 0, 180, _SERVO_DEFAULT_LOW_RESOLUTION, _SERVO_DEFAULT_HIGH_RESOLUTION );
    servo_setVref( _SERVO_VREF_3300 );
    servo_setMode( _SERVO_REG_MODE_1, _SERVO_MODE1_RESTART_ENABLE | _SERVO_MODE1_USE_ALL_CALL_ADR );
    servo_sleep();
    servo_setFREQ( 30 ); // 30 Hz
    servo_setMode( _SERVO_REG_MODE_1,_SERVO_MODE1_RESTART_ENABLE| _SERVO_MODE1_AUTO_INCREMENT_ENABLE | _SERVO_MODE1_USE_ALL_CALL_ADR );
}
void main(){

     ANSELA = 0;
     PORTA = 0;
     TRISA = 0;
     
     PORTC = 0;
     TRISC = 0;



    applicationInit();
    servo_start();
    while (1){
    
            applicationTask();
    }
    servo_stop();
}
```